# How to create a proper PHP Background process?

Tags: php, message-queue, zeromq, background-process, nohup

I am using the linux command `nohup php filename.php &` to create a background php process. The problem here is that, if there are any changes in the files included in `filename.php` or even the file itself, I have to kill the current process and start it again. Is there any way to prevent this, so that no restart is required on code update, because I do not want any downtime(because of killing and restarting the process) in my application. If there is no other way around this, then would anyone suggest an alternate approach?

**EDIT 1**

I am using ZeroMQ for communication between the main process, and this background process. The background process binds to a particular TCP port, say 555. Now, if I try to start a new process, and try to bind it to the same port, it gives an error, as the port is already in use. And thus, I need to kill the process before starting a new one.

**EDIT 2**

Please check my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189154/is-this-the-right-way-to-use-a-messaging-queue) for in-dept explanation of my complete problem with sample code.

Comment: How about, start a new process with the amended code before killing the old process? Would that work

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using ZeroMQ for communication between the main process, and this background process. The background process binds to a particular TCP port, say 555. Now, if I try to start a new process, and try to bind it to the same port, it gives an error, as the port is already in use. And thus, I need to kill the process before starting a new one.

Comment: The PHP script is loaded once when execution starts. There doesn't seem to be any way around this. If your background process is a constant loop you could separate out the code in the loop into a different file and call that file via `exec` or `shell_exec` that way you're forcing the script to reload on each iteration.

Comment: @apokryfos Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189154/is-this-the-right-way-to-use-a-messaging-queue) question of mine, which is a more in-depth version of the same problem. I think u will be able to help me out on this.

Comment: Would it work if your code looped around the bind process until it got a connection. Then the new process would pick up as soon as the old process was killed

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am not sure of that, but I will definitely give that a try. Can you please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189154/is-this-the-right-way-to-use-a-messaging-queue) question of mine in the meantime which has a more in-dept description of my problem with sample code. I had to post a simpler overall question as this, because I was not getting any response in the other question. Would appreciate it if you'd give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can not update your code while the script is running. PHP does not even do this when it is run with apache. However PHP does check before a new request is started whether it should reload the code.

If performance is not a big issue. You could do something similar yourself. Have a main script (that does not need to change much) listen on the queue. And start a second script using proc_open for instance to run the second script and serialize the data over the pipes. Now when ever the second script is used it will be reloaded for every request.