# ZeroMQ Publish and Subscribe concurrently

Tags: c++, zeromq, publish-subscribe, distributed-system, low-latency

I'm working on a program in C++ that needs to be able to send / receive **`JSON`**-payloads from an arbitrary number of other clients.

At first, I tried to implement PubNub service, but I figured I can't get and publish messages at the same time (even using two different contexts on distinct threads). I need to be able to do that. I also found that PubNub has too much latency for my liking.

I came across the [*ZeroMQ*](http://zeromq.org/) library which has a **`PUB/SUB`** model that would suit my needs. But all [*examples*](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html) I came across explain how to implement it in a way that one process is a Publisher OR a Subscriber, **and not both at the same time**.

Ideally, I would like to program a server that would relay all messages coming from anyone, to anyone subscribed to a specific channel specified in the message. **Anyone should be able to receive and publish messages to anyone else on the network,** provided they are subscribed to the correct channel.

---

```
UPDATE 1:
```

Note : **I do not need insurance of receipt** because payload N+1 will take precedence over payload N. I want a send and forget mean of communication (UDP-like).

As requested : The *PubNub* limit of **`32 kB` per `JSON`**-payload was perfect for me, I do not need more. In fact, my payloads are around **`4 kB`** in average. All instances of clients will run on the same local network, so latency should be less than **`5 ms`** ideally. As for the number of clients, there won't be more than 4 clients subscribed to the same channel/topic at a time.

---

```
UPDATE 2 :
```

I cannot predict how many channels/topics will exist ahead of time, but it will be in the order of dozens (most of the time), hundreds (at peak). Not thousands.

---

### Questions:

**`Q1:`** - Can I implement such a behavior using `ZeroMQ` ?
**`Q2:`** - Is there any working sample demonstrating that (preferably in `C++`) ?
**`Q3:`** - If not, any suggestions for a library in `C++` ?

---

[image: pubsub architecture]

Comment: Would you kindly state a **quantitative threshold for a node-to-node process latency in `[ns]`**, after which some solution "has too much latency for your liking" **+** a working **estimate of upper bounds for an arbitrary number of other clients in `[thousands]`** + a set of working estimates on **{ min | Avg | MAX }-sizes of `JSON`-payloads in `[kB]`** -- as noted above in your text? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @HippolyteBarraud for your kind updates. What may be the resulting amount of clients inside the same collision domain, if taking the said max 4 per channel / topic multiplied by a theoretical ( unspecified yet ) maximum count of possible topics? Thanks for quantitative details the architecture is strongly dependent on.

Comment: @user3666197 : Sorry for my lack of precisions. The question should be complete now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **`ZeroMQ  :`** is capable of serving this task well within scales given above
>   **`nanomsg :`**  is capable of serving this task too, a need to cross-check ports/bindings for clients
>
> ### Design review:

- <kbd>client</kbd> instances are not persistent, may freely appear on their own, may freely disappear on their own or on error
- <kbd>client</kbd> instance decides on it's own, what it is about to `PUB`-lish as a message payload
- <kbd>client</kbd> instance decides on it's own, what it is about to `SUB`-scribe to as an actual incoming stream of messages `TOPIC`-filter
- <kbd>client</kbd> instance exchanges ( sends ), on it's own, a plain, non-multipart, `JSON`-formatted messages it has prepared / produced
- <kbd>client</kbd> instance collects ( receives ) messages for which it assumes to be in the same, non-multipart, `JSON`-formatted shape and for which an attempt to get 'em locally-processed will take place after a receive is complete
- maximum # of <kbd>client</kbd>-instances is not exceeding a low number of hundreds
- maximum size of any `JSON`-formatted <kbd>payload</kbd> is less than **`32 kB`**, about a `4 kB` on average
- maximum latency acceptable on an E2E process-to-process delivery across a common LAN-collision domain is under **`5,000 [usec]`**
- <kbd>server</kbd> instance is a central-role and a persistent entity
- <kbd>server</kbd> instance provides a known transport-class `URL`-target for all *late-joiners'*`.connect()`-s

> **Proposal:**
>   
>   <kbd>**server**</kbd> may deploy multiple behaviours to meet the given goals, using both the `PUB` and `SUB` behaviours, and provides a code-driven, fast, `SUB`-side attached, non-blocking event-loop `.poll()` with aligned re-transmission of any of it's **`SUB`**-side `.recv()`-ed payloads to it's **`PUB`**-side, currently `.connect()`-ed, audience ( live <kbd>client</kbd> instances ):
>   set `s_SUB_recv = aZmqCONTEXT.socket( zmq.SUB );`
>   and `s_PUB_send = aZmqCONTEXT.socket( zmq.PUB );`
>   for performance reasons, that are not so tough here, one may also segregate workload-streams' processing by mapping each one on disjunct sub-sets of the multiple created I/O-threads:
>   map `s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_AFFINITY, 0 );`
>   and `s_PUB_send.setsockopt( ZMQ_AFFINITY, 1 );`
>   
>   set `s_PUB_send.bind( "tcp://localhost:8899" );`
> +
>   set `s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE,  "" );    // forever *every*-TOPIC`
>   set `s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_MAXMSGSIZE, 32000 ); // protective ceiling`
>   set `s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_CONFLATE,   True );  // retain just the last msg`
>   set `s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER,     0 );     // avoid blocking`
>   set `s_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_TOS,        anAppToS_NETWORK_PRIO_CODE );`
>   and `s_SUB_recv.bind( "tcp://localhost:8888" );      // [PUB]s .connect()`
>   Similarly,
>   <kbd>**client**</kbd> instance may deploy a reverse-facing tandem of both a `PUB`-endpoint and `SUB`-endpoint, ready to `.connect()` to a known transport-target-`URL`.
>   The <kbd>client</kbd> specific subscription locally decides, what is to get filtered from the incoming stream of messages ( prior to `ZeroMQ v.3.1 API` the plentitude of all messages will get delivered to each <kbd>client</kbd> instance over the transport class, however since **`API v.3.1+`**, the topic-filter is being operated on the `PUB`-side, which in the desired modus-operandi eliminates the wasted volumes of data over the network, but at the same time, this increases the `PUB`-side processing overhead ( **ref.:** remarks on a principle of increased multi-I/O-threads mapping / performance boost above )
>   set `c_SUB_recv = aZmqCONTEXT.socket( zmq.SUB );`
>   and `c_PUB_send = aZmqCONTEXT.socket( zmq.PUB );`
>   unless the payload-assembly/processing overhead grows close to the permitted End-to-End latency threshold, there shall be no need to separate / segregate the `ZeroMQ` low-level I/O-threads here:
>   map `c_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_AFFINITY, 0 );`
>   and `c_PUB_send.setsockopt( ZMQ_AFFINITY, 1 );`
>   
>   set `c_PUB_send.connect( "tcp://server:8888" );      // reverse .bind on [SUB]`
> +
>   set `c_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE,  "" );    // modified on-the-fly`
>   set `c_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_MAXMSGSIZE, 32000 ); // protective ceiling`
>   set `c_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_CONFLATE,   True );  // take just last`
>   set `c_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER,     0 );     // avoid blocking`
>   set `c_SUB_recv.setsockopt( ZMQ_TOS,        anAppToS_NETWORK_PRIO_CODE );`
>   and `c_SUB_recv.connect( "tcp://server:8899" );`

### Discussion:

For hobby projects, there is not much more needed on the messaging-infrastructure, nevertheless for more serious domains, there are additional services both the <kbd>server</kbd> and <kbd>client</kbd> instances ought have some further formal-communication pattern behaviours added.
 - <kbd>**`r/KBD`**</kbd> for a remote keyboard, with a `CLI`-alike ad-hoc inspection utilities
 - <kbd>**`KEEP_ALIVE`**</kbd> transponders for allowing a system-wide state- / perf-monitoring
 - <kbd>**`SIG_EXIT`**</kbd> handlers for allowing a system-wide / instance-specific `SIG_EXIT`s
 - <kbd>`distributed syslog`</kbd> service to allow to safely collect / store a non-blocking replica of log-records ( be it during debug phase or performance-tuninc phase or production-grade records-of-evidence collecting )
 - <kbd>`Identity Management`</kbd> tools for audit-trails et al
 - <kbd>**`WhiteList/BlackList`**</kbd> for adding robustness to the infrastructure to make it better immune to DoS-attack / poisoning erroneous NIC traffic-bursts et al
 - <kbd>**`Adaptive Node re-Discovery`**</kbd> for smarter / ad-hoc infrastructure design and status monitoring or when multi-role / ( N + M )-shaded active hot-standby role-handover/takeover scenarios et al come onto the stage

### Summary

`A1`: Yes, fully within ZeroMQ capabilities
`A2`: Yes, C++ code-samples in the ZeroMQ book / Guides available
`A3`: Ref.: A1, plus may like indepth remark [in Martin SUSTRIK's post on "Differences between `nanomsg` and `ZeroMQ`"](http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html)

Hope you will enjoy the powers of distributed processing, be it supported by `ZeroMQ` or `nanomsg` or both.

**Only one's own imagination is the limit.**

If interested in [**further details**, one might love the book referred to in the **The Best Next Step** section of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260714/3666197)

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth answer ! You answered my question far beyond my expectations. After testing both libraries, I am leaning toward nanomsg for its simplicity and memory-friendliness. I will have no trouble adapting your answer for my need.

Answer (score 0):

> **`Q1:`** - Can I implement such a behavior using ZeroMQ ?

Definitely yes; but probably not using the `PUB/SUB` sockets.

The way to do it using `PUB/SUB` is this: for every node in the system, you make one `PUB` socket and one `SUB` socket, and connect the single `SUB` socket to the `PUB` sockets of *all* other nodes and set your subscription filter accordingly. This is limited in its usefulness because (I think) you need to set the same filter for all your connections. Note that you definitely should *NOT* create more than one context in each node.

If your total number of nodes is low (e.g. 10-20 or fewer,) you can make one `PUB` socket and N-1 `SUB` sockets per node (still all in one context,) and connect each `SUB` socket to each of the `PUB` sockets of the other nodes.

If you have clear notions of client and server nodes, you can use the newer `CLIENT/SERVER` sockets (available in `4.2` or `4.1`, I believe.) This will be more elegant and probably easier to manage, but you'll have to implement the content filtering ("channels") yourself; which can be pretty easy or a little involved, depending on what exactly you want to do.

> **`Q2:`** - Is there any working sample demonstrating that (preferably in C++) ?

Not that I know of.

> **`Q3:`** - If not, any suggestions for a library in C++ ?

I'd still suggest `ZeroMQ`, for its relatively light weight, simple and elegant interface, comprehensive functionality, and ability to work in and with many languages. There are a lot of socket combos to choose from. If worse comes to worst, you can always use `PAIR` sockets everywhere.

Comment: With all due respect, what is a rationale for an assumption above not to use more than one **`Context()`** instance in a `ZeroMQ` application? Do you have any citation / source for this opinion?

Comment: Yes I know that ultimately, this solution always exists. But the idea was to implement this as a last resort, preferably using something more simple if possible. I would prefer to manage lots of sockets only on the server side. Leaving the clients with two sockets at max.

Answer (score 0):

**`nanomsg`** with **`BUS`** protocol, see http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html

Comment: Yes, Martin Sustrik has spinned-off another marvelous piece of messaging library in **`nanomsg`**, nevertheless the `NN_BUS` does not provide per-se AFAIK the requested service components asked above by OP ( topic-filtering, node (re)-discovery updates et al ) so design / architecture still heavily depends on details about latency thresholds + capacity estimates asked above to be yet clarified.

Comment: I took a look at **`nanomsg`**'s BUS protocol. While at first it seems to not provide exactly what I need, the author talks about a _"non-trivial, broker based, topologie"_ where there is a man in the middle transfering all messages to everybody else ([as explained here](http://250bpm.com/blog:17)).
@user3666197 : Do you think it will do, considering the estimates i provided above ?

Comment: @user3666197 that's true, quite some code should be written on top of **nanomsg**. But having BUS protocol should simplify things a lot in a OP scenario, I think. Would be pain-in-the-.. to do that on top of **0mq**

Comment: @HippolyteBarraud yes, **nanomsg** with BUS is not exactly fits the bill, you'll need more code. But out of three messaging libs I dealt with (**MPI**, **0mq**, **nanomsg**) last one seems to have at least decent foundation for what you need. Maybe other messaging libs are better suited for the task on hand (**RabbitMQ**? have no idea about it)

Comment: With full respect to your insights, my experience made me believe no **single-archetype design meets a real-world, production-grade ecosystem's requirements** ( even, or might be **the more** if you are being sold this fiction from naive PMO Project Managers & ad-hoc CXO Project Sponsors ). Countless examples apply. Btw, I appreciate a lot Martin's  fresh & lovely blog posts on 250bpm.

Comment: No, @SeverinPappadeus, any Broker-based ( persistence motivated mastodont-in-porcelain ) solution is not the way forward. Funny to read an MPI in a context of a smart & lightweight messaging. MPI paved the way in scientific cluster's environments with rather naive-(mass)-distributed code-designs, not a resource of a 1st choice in an unstructured ad-hoc smart messaging.

Comment: @user3666197 `Funny to read an MPI in a context of a smart & lightweight messaging.` ;))). No, I wouldn't advice to use **MPI** for the OP task